# Data structure with relationship via Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am using a table with PK as well as the other FK. How can I do this in FireBase?

[image]

Comment: NoSQL data modeling is a really broad topic, that is hard to do justice in a Stack Overflow answer. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thank you.I will examine this

Answer (score 1):

This should be the .json for your database.

```
{
      "Artists" : {
        "Tracks" : {
          "id": int,
          "name" : varchar(100),
          "rating" : int,
          "Artists_id" : int
        },
        "name" : varchar(100),
        "genre" : varchar(100)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I will try this